# while saving the filter on reload/redirection,the Edit Button and Export to Excel button on Kendo Grid is not working

Tags: kendo-grid

Am working on the **Kendo UI** and my goal is to **retain the kendo-grid filter on page reload or while redirecting, I can able to retain the filter after page reload/redirecting** but facing the issues mentioned below,

1. **Export to Excel button gets removed** after reload or while redirecting.
2. On click of **Edit button in the grid is not working** after saving the filter in the localstorage, but it works before saving into the localstorage. (On clicking the edit button it calls the **show()** which intern calls **grid_dataBound()**)

```
//Edit button column in kendo:
columns.Command(command =>
 {
  command.Custom(Resources.VerificationEntries.txtEdit).Click("show");
  command.Destroy().Text(Resources.Kendo.txtDel);
  }).Width(200).HtmlAttributes(new { });
}

//code logic to save the filter to local storage
 $(document).ready(function () {   
     $("#gridEntries").data("kendoGrid").setOptions(JSON.parse(localStorage["GridSettings"]));
    });
    function grid_dataBound() {
        localStorage.clear('GridSettings');
        localStorage["GridSettings"] = kendo.stringify($("#gridEntries").data("kendoGrid").getOptions());
    }
//On click of edit
function show(e) {
    grid_dataBound();
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var vID = dataItem.VID;
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Update", "Vest")?VID=' + vID;
    }
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors in the console log? Also where does your Export to Excel button live? It might be helpful to see all of the mvc razor grid code along with any relevant Javascript.

Perhaps using the command.Edit rather than command.Custom would be more helpful. Then you could add `Events(e=e>Edit("show"))` to use your Javascript function.

When it comes to editing there is an "Edit" mode/event where a user enters their changes then a "Save" mode/event where the data is actually sent to the controller. You may be wanting to tie into the save event rather than edit. I also suspect your `e.preventDefault();` might be part of the source of your grid breaking.

If you're looking for a whole seperate window you could do a column custom template where you add a button (through html) that has a javascript function where you can pass in any model values, such as vID.

What are you trying to accomplish through your edit button?